# What exactly hibernate enableExtendedEnhancement does?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-5.x, hibernate-tools

I know this might not be the right place to ask a question like this,
but so far `enableExtendedEnhancement` is not documented and I was not able to find any resources on this topic.

Please explain this in detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Answer (score 1):

Normally, Hibernate expects you to access persistent fields via getters and setters. If you use byte code enhancement and access a field in some other way, except getter or setter, Hibernate may fail to register that the field became dirty.

The parameter `enableExtendedEnhancement` of `hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin` enables additional analysis and interception of field access outside getters and setters. It is processed in [FieldAccessEnhancer](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/bytecode/enhance/internal/bytebuddy/FieldAccessEnhancer.java). However, in the [source code of the plugin](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/295eb870a3d4d424a8d8973fc8279d4883c12f76/tooling/hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/hibernate/orm/tooling/maven/MavenEnhancePlugin.java#L147), it's recommended to use this setting at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

a mystical option enableExtendedEnhancement intended for fine-tuning of the bytecode enhancement. this is completely described [here](https://forketyfork.medium.com/hibernate-extended-bytecode-enhancement-ae73962c9bf4)